# Basic REST API retrieving json file from GET -- instead of the xml opening in IE Browswer

Tags: json, rest, api, google-chrome, model-view-controller

I created a small api which I am testing out In IE Browser

This URL should invoke the GET:
http://localhost:51722/api/quotes

Instead of returning the XML within the browser itself, the browser asks me if I want to open or save my quotes.json file from local host.

[image: PICTURE OF PROBLEM]

On my other computer, it just straight away opens AN XML  file in the browser itself (NOT json, with option to open after saving, as per screenshot).

You might not need to look at the code, but here it is anyway:

```
using QuotesApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace QuotesApi.Controllers
{
    public class QuotesController : ApiController
    {
        static List<Quote> _quotes = new List<Quote>()
        {
            new Quote() {Id=0,Author ="Einstein",Description="Imagination is more important thank knowledge",Title="Imagination" },
            new Quote() {Id=1,Author ="Einstein",Description="Imagination is more important thank knowledge",Title="Imagination" }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Quote> Get()
        {
            return _quotes;
        }

        public void Post([FromBody]Quote quote)
        {
            _quotes.Add(quote);
        }

        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] Quote quote)
        {
            _quotes[id] = quote;

        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            _quotes.RemoveAt(id);
        }
    }

}
```

another file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace QuotesApi.Models
{
    public class Quote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use IE.
Use chrome for development